# How to geolocate an android device by using Network Location Provider

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am trying to develop an Android application that can be used to find location of a friend who has also installed the application. The application will find location not using GPS but through **Android Network location provider**.

The person who want to get the location of a friend will send a particular SMS to the friend, the friend phone will then process the SMS in background, find the location using network location provider and reply the requester with a SMS containing the location.

So, I need help regarding (1): how to find location using Network Location Provider, and (2): how to implement the service that can read the incoming message in background and activate the application to do some job.
Answers to any of the above two queries is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reto Meier has put out a lot of good information regarding the right way to do location.  A good starting point is here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

For the SMS piece, you are going to need to setup a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).  Here is an example to get you started: http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.com/2010/10/receiving-sms-using-broadcastreceiver.html